# What is the class similar to hero-unit class in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I could not find hero-unit css class (present in bootstrap 2) in bootstrap 3. Are there any class similar to hero-unit in bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: don't forget the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#type-components

Answer (score 50, accepted):

it was renamed. Now use `class="jumbotron"`

Comment: And it seems to have been renamed or removed in the intervening 9 years.

Answer (score 5):

Hero Unit is renamed to "Jumbotron".

Here is a link to the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron

Answer (score 0):

The "jumbotron" (formerly "hero-unit") class has been removed in Bootstrap 5 because you can create the effect with other classes.

There is a migration guide which points you to an example:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#jumbotron